# Django ternary relationships

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am quite new to Django and I am having troubles creating the right models for this particular problem.

I have users, and they own a "Wallet". This wallet should be a list of currencies/values.

Currencies are in a table with just a "name" field. ID : 1 Name : EUR

And I'd like my wallet to be something like : Currency : EUR, Value : 0, Currency : USD, Value : 1000

For this, I'd usually use a ternary with another table let's say Balance. Where Balance would have : Wallet ID : 1, Currency ID : 1, Value : 50

I want to do the right thing here, and I am not too sure how to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Class Wallet(models.Model):
    # if a user has only one wallet
    user = models.OneToOneField('User')
    # if a user has multiple wallets
    # user = models.ForeignKey('User')

class Balance(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    value    = models.DecimalField()
    wallet   = models.ForeignKey('Wallet')

# to get a user's wallet:
user_wallet = user.wallet
# get all balances
user_balance = user.wallet.balance_set.all()
```

**Edit:**

`currency` doesn't have to be a model on its own, because there aren't so many currencies in there. Also you can avoid joining additional tables when you query. Use `choices` on `CharField` instead:

```
CURRENCIES = (
    (u'USD', u'US Dollars'),
    (u'EUR', u'Euro'),
    # ...
)

currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CURRENCIES)
```

But again, if you have a lot of currencies, go for a model.

If you are using `OneOnOne` relationship between `Wallet` and `User`, then it doesn't matter where is it. But if you have multiple wallets for one user, I think you should figure out why `user` is in `Wallet`, right?

Comment: Thanks ok that's pretty much what I had in mind. Could you explain why the relationship between the wallet and the user is not modelled with a wallet field in the user model instead of user field in the wallet model ?
Also, small detail, Currency is a table, so I am going to use : 
currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
instead of the CharField